# Form custom repeated values mapping

Tags: scala, playframework

```
val myForm = Form(
  mapping(
    values -> optional(seq(text))
)(MyCaseClass.apply)(MyCaseClass.unapply))
```

My problem is that I don't want to have request with `values[0]`, `values[1]`, etc. I want to have request with `values0`, `values1`, etc.

Is it possible? How to override repeated fields pattern to match with my values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? What does an instance of the `Form` class look like? What are the type signatures? What are the type signatures of the `mapping` and `optional` functions?

Comment: @davidrpugh Well, it's Play's `Form`. You can check it [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms). 

Seq looks like 
`def seq[A](mapping: Mapping[A]): Mapping[Seq[A]] = RepeatedMapping(mapping).transform(_.toSeq, _.toList)` 

I created this `customSeq` and override **indexes** method in `object RepeatedMapping` from ` play.api.data` but there's no success.